# How to display the content of a local file in browser using java script ( code to be compatible for all browsers)?

Tags: javascript, html

I am planning to create a application on my local . I need a javascript code that to render the content from whichever file I am selecting from my system using html file-upload input box. Referred to the below link but 
http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=1645 where the code is not compatible for other browsers,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't think there are any clean cross-browser solutions for this as of now.

Comment: @aSanthosh: I think the File API's are supported in IE 10 and in latest safari .As the link says it's already supported in chrome and firefox so this should be compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons you can't open a file from the browser. What you can actually do is upload it to the server and then write it back to the page.
To upload the file I suggest you uploadify or jquery upload.

You are welcome.

If you don't care about the cross-browsing support then:

```
<input id="file" type="file" multiple="" onchange="startRead()">

<pre><code id="output"></code></pre>


function startRead() {
    //obtain input element through DOM  
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    if (file) {
        getAsText(file);
    }
}
function getAsText(readFile) {
    var reader;
    try {
        reader = new FileReader();
    } catch (e) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Error: seems File API is not supported on your browser";
        return;
    }
    // Read file into memory as UTF-8      
    reader.readAsText(readFile, "UTF-8");
    // handle success and errors

    reader.onload = loaded;
    reader.onerror = errorHandler;
}

function loaded(evt) {
    // Obtain the read file data    
    var fileString = evt.target.result;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = fileString;
}
function errorHandler(evt) {
    if (evt.target.error.code == evt.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR) {
        // The file could not be read
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Error reading file..."
    }
}
```

Comment: The question includes a link to a guide which does it **is** possible!

Comment: @Quentin, aSanthosh asks for "How to display the content of a local file in browser using java script ( code to be compatible for all browsers)?", the only way it to be cross-browser compatible is to do it the old way, not using the file api.

Answer (score 0):

We are developing kinds of web-based GUI editor. This issue have been the problem for long time.

As I know, the method in the site you mentioned is the only way. We are using HTML5 File System.

Before this, We've considered using kinds of Flash module, local web server, dropbox, ...